# Passing argument as array in Symfony 4.4 Process Component

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-4.4

This is the process command I have to execute, The argument contactIds is an array.

```
 $process = new Process([
            "php",
            "../fairgate4/bin/console",
            "contactlist:remove",
            $contactIds  // array
        ]);
 $process->start();
```

Symfony throws an error for this argument :

Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Process\Process::escapeArgument() must be of the type string or null, array given

Comment: we can pass the argument as string only, I have imploded and passed

Answer (score 0):

```
 $contactIdStr = implode(' ',contactIds); // converted array to string
 $process = new Process([
            "php",
            "../fairgate4/bin/console",
            "contactlist:remove",
            $contactIdStr
        ]);
 $process->start();
```

Comment: we can try this too, Process::fromShellCommandline('command to execute');